# Task.delay inside Task.Run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Here I have the following piece of code:

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>();

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var person = new Person { Id = i };
    list.Add(person);
}

stopwatch.Start();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
stopwatch.Stop();
```

I assume that I will have about **100 seconds** in the result of the stopwatch.
But I have **1,1092223**.

I think I missing something, can you help me to explain why?

Comment: How many CPU cores (hardware threads) do you have?

Comment: Why do you expect 100s? You're launching all of these tasks in ***parallel***. They each take just over a second to complete. Everything looks consistent here.

Comment: Task.Run will execute the delegate argument on the first free thread in the default thread pool, and the pool may add additional threads if there’s enough free CPU cores to run queued jobs concurrently.

Comment: @Dai "the pool may add additional threads"... for such a trivial workload, this is unlikely to happen in this case.

Comment: `I assume that I will have about 100 seconds in the result of the stopwatch.` Why do you assume that?

Comment: Can you talk us through what you think `Task.Run` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your confusion might come from the await keyword in `await Task.Delay(1000);`

But this holds only for the innerworking of the taskmethod. Inside the loop the next iteration will be performed immidiately after `Task.Run` is executed. So all Tasks will be started in close succession and then run in parallel. (As far as the system has free threads at hand of course) The system takes care how, when and in which order they can be executed.

In the end in this line:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

you actually wait for the slowest of them (or the one started as last).

To fullfill your expectation your code should actually look like this:

```
public async Task RunAsPseudoParallel()
{
    List<Person> list = new List<Person>();

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var person = new Person { Id = i };
        list.Add(person);
    }

    stopwatch.Start();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        });
    }
    stopwatch.Stop()
}
```

Disclaimer: But this code is quite nonsensical, because it uses async functionality to implement a synchronous process. In this scenario you can simply leave out the `Task.Run` call and use a simple `Thread.Sleep(1000)`.

Comment: @Fildor isn't that the same? If the Task got its CPU slot to run then it will run for those ~1000 msec. The last one to get started is the last one to finish... or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't like "start all tasks in parallel". Literally you don't actually know if they all will be started in parallel

Comment: @MongZhu Thank you for your answer. What do I have to do if I need to execute my tasks with Delay? Or my question isn't correct?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlenko " Or my question isn't correct?" is there something like a correct question? ;) I probably misunderstood you. So you want your tasks start one after the other with a delay of 1000 msec between them?

Comment: @Shymep I rephrased the answer. Do you "like" the wording better now? You can also edit my answer at any time and suggest a better wording. No problem

Comment: @AlexanderPavlenko Or do you want to start them in parallel, but then wait a second before a certain processing shall take place?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes, await Task.Delay(1000) confused me. But now, I think to add the delay in my implementation is wrong. But you have right understood me. I assumed to add Delay between tasks. I think your implementation will execute what I want. Thank you.

Comment: @MongZhu yes, the reason for my comment is avoid misunderstanding. I realize that you understand the subject.

Comment: @Shymep " the reason for my comment is avoid misunderstanding" I understood that part. I also appreciate your comment. :) otherwise I wouldn't habe reacted to it and changed my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlenko glad I could help. " I think your implementation will execute what I want." you really should not use this code that I posted. I wrote a disclaimer to prevent people from it. If you need the processing to be one after the other then write a normal loop and be done with it :) or do you have in your real code a method that is async which you have to call in this loop instead of `Task.Run` ?

Answer (score 1):

Delays are always approximate.

You are limited by when the task scheduler chooses to run the delegate you pass to `Task.Run`. It may be executing other tasks and be unwilling to start up more threads. Or, it may launch a new thread -- which while not slow is also not free and costs time too.

You are limited by when the task scheduler chooses to resume your code after the delay completes.

You're also limited by the OS scheduler, which may be allocating CPU time to other processes/threads and end up delaying the thread that would execute your code.

Because you are launching multiple tasks, you are seeing all of these per-task variables compound into an even larger delay.